# mkdir //.ssh: Permission denied at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/Util/Hosts.pm line 92

Tags: mod-perl

I'm using "Net::SFTP" in perl cgi file to put files to a windows M/C from my dev box.

After adding below new directory manually (with 0777 permissions) everything works fine:

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/.ssh
-bash-4.1$ cd ..
-bash-4.1$ ls -ltra | grep .ssh
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan 23 23:57 .ssh
```

Problem (if I don't add above directory manually ) here is as per my understanding:
Apache is running cgi with user as "nobody" which do not have permissions to make directory after connection is established via sftp and I'm getting below error messages in logs:

```
xxx.xxx.net: Reading configuration data /.ssh/config
xxx.xxx.net: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
xxx.xxx.net: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.com, port 22.
xxx.xxx.net: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 5.17 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 5.58: free only for personal non-commercial use^M
Math::BigInt: couldn't load specified math lib(s), fallback to Math::BigInt::Calc at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Crypt/DH.pm line 6
xxx.xxx.net: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.34, protocol version 2.0.
xxx.xxx.net: No compat match: 5.17 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 5.58: free only for personal non-commercial use^M.
xxx.xxx.net: Connection established.
xxx.xxx.net: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
xxx.xxx.net: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
xxx.xxx.net: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
xxx.xxx.net: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
xxx.xxx.net: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply.
xxx.xxx.net: Received host key, type 'ssh-dss'.
xxx.xxx.net: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xxx.com' to the list of known hosts.
**mkdir //.ssh: Permission denied at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/SSH/Perl/Util/Hosts.pm line 92**
```

I tried to solve this problem with different methods given over internet but nothing is working for me.

Can anybody suggest possible solution?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem myself and you are correct that it is a permissions issue.  When your nobody process tries to connect to the remote server, it wants to write the remote host key to a file.  This is the step that is failing in your error message (Hosts.pm line 92).

My solution was to create a nobody-writable location for the NET::SFTP to write the known_hosts file and to specify that location before you construct your NET::SFTP connection.

```
$ENV{HOME} =  '/nobody/writable/location/';
```

You can find more information on this problem at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=599078